# logstash - split a message by newlines

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

**logstash**

trying to split a message by newlines (`"\n"`) with no success so far. I need to retrieve the last line only.

Logstash code:

```
mutate{
    split => ["traceback", "\n"]
    add_field => {"traceback_last_line" => "%{[traceback][-1]}"}
}
```

Input:

```
[traceback] = 
  "File "<doctest...>", line 10, in <module>
    lumberjack()
  File "<doctest...>", line 4, in lumberjack
    bright_side_of_death()
IndexError: tuple index out of range"
```

Answer (score 1):

I Used `gsub` to replace `'\n'` and then, the usual sequence of mutate.split

```
    mutate {
       copy => { "traceback" => "traceback_tmp" }
    }
    mutate {
       gsub => ["traceback_tmp", "\n", "::"]
    }
    mutate {
       split => {"traceback_tmp" => "::"}
       add_field => ["traceback_summary", "%{[traceback_tmp][-1]}"]
       remove_field => ["traceback_tmp"]
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason for the intermediate `gsub` step? Why not split directly on newlines and avoid the possibility that there might already be some occurrences of `'::'` in your input that might cause spurious splitting?

Comment: `split => ["traceback", "\n"]` just does not work. It's possible to have a more failproof string to replace with "THIS_IS_MY_NLINE"

Comment: I wonder if the code passed in the `"\n"` is being processed with `eval` further down? Try single quotes instead when passing the newline to `split` to prevent it from being resolved, e.g. `split => {"traceback_tmp" => '\n'}`